# Getting BTC-E historical prices

Tags: btce

Is there a way to get BTC-E older ticks? 
On their api docs I only found how to get the current Tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not from Btc-e though you can probably get them from [bitcoin charts](http://bitcoincharts.com/) or start keeping your own and then just query that (thats what I did.) Btc-e's API sucks, but heres a [project](https://github.com/pskupinski/node-btc-e) that makes several API calls not in their [official documentation](https://btc-e.com/api/documentation).

Comment: The 'trades not in their documentation' are just documented elsewhere... https://btc-e.com/page/2 (open up the API bit at the bottom of the FAQ). They are separate because they are part of the public api.